# Moving the position of the data for too long job title in awesome-CV

Tags: awesome-cv

I am using Awesome CV. The template is available [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-cv/dfnvtnhzhhbm).

In `\cventry`, if the job title is too long, the position of date is not excellent. I would like to move the date to the top, as in the following picture.

How can I do that?

[image]